Properties of a $C^1$-function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$
Assume we have a $C^1$-function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

$f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$

I was asking myself if it is the case that there exists a point $x_0 \in (0,1)$
with $f(x_0)<0$ and $f'(x_0)>0$.
I‘m pretty sure that such a point has to exist, but all my efforts to proof it failed at some point.
Thanks in advance.

How about mean value theorem between $0$ and the point where it cuts the x-axis (which is guranteed to exist by intermediate value theorem)?

@HackR i thought about that, but i don’t see where i can guarantee that this point must have a negative function value.

You are finding a point between $0$ (where $f$ is negative) and the point where you first touch the X-axis (where $f$ is zero), thus your functional value at that point is also negative (if it is positive or 0, you must have hit the X-axis sometime before).

By continuity, suppose  $x' \in (0, 1)$ is the first value such that $f(x') =0$ (using, say, the intermediate value theorem). Now $f$ is continuous on $[0, x']$ and differentiable on $(0, x')$, so by the mean value theorem, there is some $x_0 \in (0, x')$ such that
$$f'(x') = \frac{f(x') - f(0)}{x' - 0} = \frac{-f(0)}{x'} > 0.$$

Haha! This was my comment just now! +1

That was exactly my solution, but i wasn‘t sure if i could state that i can find the „first“ root, because I thought about functions that have an infinite number of roots if x approaches zero.

@LebesgueLukas I think by continuity that such a function would have to have $f(0) = 0$.

@kipf I also think so, but thanks for the answer and comments.

@kipf Yes indeed. Just take the sequence of roots going to $0$.

@kipf of course! Sometimes it‘s the most obvious answer! :)

Let $x^*$ be the first point at which $f(x^*) = 0$, then $f(0)+\int_0^{x^*} f'(t) dt = 0$. Since $f(0)<0$, there must exist some (in fact, many) $t^* \in (0,x^*)$ such that $f'(t^*) > 0$.

That was ephemeral.
